# How to change the origin of .glp objects?

Tags: objects, transforms, origin

I'm having a problem with the origin of .glb models. The origin as it is clear in the picture is far from the geometry which makes it difficult to scale andtransform the object.
[image]
Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as ".glb objects" in Blender. The moment you import a file of any supported 3d format to Blender whatever information that is in the file gets converted into data formats native to Blender. So there is nothing different about the objects that get imported from GLTF format and you set the origin the same way as you do that for any other objects in Blender.

This is basic functionality and is very well covered by any basic tutorials and even in [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html#):

> Set Origin
>
> Mode : Object Mode
>
> Menu : Object ‣ Set Origin
>
> The object origin and geometry can be moved relative to each other and
> to the 3D cursor.
>
> Type Geometry to Origin Moves the model to the origin and this way the
> origin of the object will also be at the center of the object.
>
> Origin to Geometry Moves the origin to the center of the object.
>
> Origin to 3D Cursor Moves the origin of the model to the position of
> the 3D cursor.
>
> Origin to Center of Mass Moves the origin to the calculated center of
> mass of model (assuming the mesh has a uniform density).
>
> Center Median Point Center, Bounding Box Center
>
> Tip
>
> To transform an object’s origin directly, enable Affect Only Origins
> in the Tool Settings Options.

Here is what the tip is about:

[image]

With this enabled you can use regular transform operators (G, R, S) for transforming the origin:

[image]

I show that snap functionality works with this in the GIF, because that's useful, but it's just one random example out all functionality of transform operators. Everything that works for any other transform operations works for transforming the origin point.

> ...which makes it difficult to scale and transform the object.

Location of the origin point should not make it difficult to scale and transform the objects. You clearly lack knowledge about all the functionality related to transforming objects in Blender. I would suggest watching some tutorials to fill that gap. Good place to start could be [the official tutorials recommended on blender.org website](https://www.blender.org/support/), however the internet is full of good tutorials so simple web search will help you find plenty of others. There would be nothing wrong with asking about this basic stuff on BSE or forums, it's just that this information is really well covered and you can find a lot of really high quality resources online even absolutely free that will communicate the basics better and in more efficient manner than BSE answers letting you save yourself a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.